# how to expand tabelviewcell size,when im selecting on it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

My output is shown in below image.

[image]

Here in description label, I want to show only 3 line, on selecting particular cell that should be expanded to show remaining lines.

Please guide on the same.

Comment: Hope this helps - https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: If you have set the constraints properly then you just have to do the below steps, 1. Set the Desc label numberOfLines property to 3 from storyboard 2. and then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath just change labels numberOfLines property to 0 3. and reload the cell.

Comment: @barath can u post code which i need to add on didselectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath]; UILabel *labelDesc = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag: <tag>]; labelDesc.numberOfLines = 0; labelDesc.lineBreakMode =  NSLineBreakModeWordWrap; [self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];

Comment: thanks its working. but if click on one cell that all cells are showing all content.i want output from  respected cell only